# Weird results of form:option in form:select

Tags: java, spring, forms, jsp, select

I am trying to preselect some values from a `form:select` tag. So, let's take a look at my sample class below:

```
public class Post
{
    private boolean anonymize;
    private boolean videoRequired;

    /* getters, setters */
}
```

As you can see, there are two boolean fields. I'm using the first one in JSP like this:

```
<label>Anonymize</label>
<form:select path="anonymize" id="anonymize" class="form-control">
    <form:option value="true" label="Yes" selected="${ (post.anonymize) ? true : ''}" />
    <form:option value="false" label="No" selected="${ (!post.anonymize) ? true : ''}" />
</form:select>
```

which, when I inspect that element, results in (let's say that `anonymize` is `true`):

```
<select id="anonymize" name="anonymize" class="form-control">
    <option selected="true" value="true">Yes</option>
    <option value="false">No</option>
</select>
```

So far so good.
Now I do the EXACT same thing with my other boolean field `videoRequired`. First the JSP:

```
<label>Video required</label>
<form:select path="videoRequired" id="videoRequired" class="form-control">
    <form:option value="true" label="Yes" selected="${ (post.videoRequired) ? true : '' }" />
    <form:option value="false" label="No" selected="${ (!post.videoRequired) ? true : '' }" />          
</form:select>
```

Which, results in (again, let's say that `videoRequired` is also `true`):

```
<label>Video required</label>
<select id="videoRequired" name="videoRequired" class="form-control">
    <option selected="true" value="true">Yes</option>
    <option value="false" selected="selected">No</option>           
</select>
```

Take a look at this line:
`<option value="false" selected="selected">No</option>`

How can this even happen? I'm stuck with this for a few hours now, I have even tried with `<c:choose>` tag and then hardcoding the `selected` attribute - it gave me the exact same weird result. Can anyone please explain where have I gone wrong? I'm pulling my brains out since I'm doing the same thing on both fields, but still one works, the other one doesn't. Btw, when I take a look at mysql, both fields are properly set.

Comment: are you passing a blank object via ModelMap from your controller? if so set the variable `anonymize` in that object to true. that will pre select the select box

Comment: I'm not using ModelMap, just Model. But your comment made me figure out the error, I "forgot" (pretty sure I did that, probably I accidently deleted it) to do this in my controller: 

`boolean videoRequired = post.isVideoRequired();
                generalForm.setVideoRequired(videoRequired);`

I'm amazed at myself ... like realy amazed -.-' Thanks man! You should write an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pre-select a `form:select` element, you can set the corresponding variable `anonymize` to true in your controller method that returns your view.

```
@Controller
public String getForm(ModelMap model, Post post){
    post.setVideoRequired(true);
    return "view-name";
}
```